# What is the equivalent of IWriterConfiguration.UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics in newer versions of CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

We are currently in the process of upgrading a bunch of old NuGet packages to the most recent version. CsvHelper has moved a bunch of stuff around between the previous version we were using (2.x) and the most recent version (12.x). The changelog doesn't mention a lot of these changes (or at least doesn't explicitly name which properties or methods were changed in each changelog entry), which has frustrated our upgrade process.

The `IWriterConfiguration.UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics` setting has disappeared in the upgrade and I'm having trouble finding out what the equivalent setting is in newer versions. I've tried to track down the change in the commit history in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper), but one of the major version number changes involved a rename of a lot of classes, meaning I'm having difficulty finding the commit where this change occurred, so I can't see what the equivalent setting is in newer versions.

We need to ensure that the behaviour of our system prior to the upgrade is identical to the new behaviour. Does anyone know how I would replicate the behaviour induced by this configuration setting in the current package version?

Comment: This feature was introduced in 2.11 and removed in 3.0 (or, at least, that version no longer has that property), along with all other Excel-specific code, if [this](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/pull/668) is to be believed, so there is no equivalent setting as such. The thread refers to a [`CsvHelperContrib`](https://github.com/CsvHelperContrib/CsvHelperContrib) repository, but that's actually empty.

Comment: This feature is very minor and `CsvWriter.WriteField` is still `virtual`, so you should have little trouble [porting the code](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/2.12/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L164) into a custom derived `CsvWriter` class.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi, thank you for finding the original implementation - that was what I was looking for in order to recreate this behaviour, but I was struggling to find it in the repo history. I'll try and recreate it as you suggested and add it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jeroen Mostert pointed out that the original implementation of the behaviour of this configuration option is in the virtual `CsvWriter.WriteField` method. Therefore, the original behaviour can be re-implemented if needed.

Due to the structure of the method, there doesn't seem to be a way to re-implement this functionality in a way that won't potentially break, or cause hard-to-detect issues, if the package maintainer changes the behaviour or implementation of `CsvWriter.WriteField` in the future. However, this derived class should work for at least the current version of CsvHelper (12.1.2):

```
public class ExcelFormatCsvWriter : CsvWriter
{
    public bool UseExcelFormat
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ExcelFormatCsvWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteField(string field, bool shouldQuote)
    {
        if (shouldQuote && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
        {
            field = field.Replace(Context.WriterConfiguration.QuoteString, Context.WriterConfiguration.DoubleQuoteString);
        }

        if (UseExcelFormat && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field) && field[0] == '0' && field.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            field = "=" + Context.WriterConfiguration.QuoteString + field + Context.WriterConfiguration.QuoteString;
        }
        else if (shouldQuote)
        {
            field = Context.WriterConfiguration.Quote + field + Context.WriterConfiguration.Quote;
        }

        Context.Record.Add(field);
    }
}
```