# QuoteString & DoubleQuoteString Replacement

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

With CsvHelper [20.0.0](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/#20-0-0), `WriterConfiguration.QuoteString` and `WriterConfiguration.DoubleQuoteString` have been removed.

I was relying on those fields to implement `UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555534/what-is-the-equivalent-of-iwriterconfiguration-useexcelleadingzerosformatfornume).

Is there another way I can access `QuoteString` and `DoubleQuoteString`?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `QuoteString` with `configuration.Quote.ToString()` and `DoubleQuoteString` with `new String(configuration.Quote, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to replace `Context.Record.Add(field)`?  Looks like the implementation of `WriteField` has changed to rely on private members

Comment: @James I don't see `CsvContext.Record`? Not sure what `Context` you mean...

Comment: sorry, I'm referring to this code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556903/10023098

Comment: @James It appears the new CsvHelper has many changes for performance; I would suggest re-writing the code sample based on the source of the current version of `CsvWriter.WriteField`. Or perhaps ask a separate question on how to re-write that sample.