# How to implement UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics in CsvHelper 20.0.0 and up?

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have been using this code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556903/10023098 to extend `CsvWriter.WriteField` and implement leading zeros.

With CsvHelper 20.0.0, `CsvContext.Record` has been removed.

I tried re-implementing the [current implementation](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L156) of `WriteField`, but the new implementation relies on several private members so I cannot recreate an overload that will have the same performance as the base class and use leading zeros.

How can I implement `UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics` for CsvHelper 20.0.0 and up?

Comment: You can't currently. Add this as a feature request and I'll put in a way to do it. I believe I just need to make a `private` method `protected` and you should be good. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues

Comment: @JoshClose Thanks!  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1699